# Pass a class parameter and return an object of that class (java)

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a public method. The public method is declared as

```
public Object createUIBean(Class c, HttpServletRequest request) {
  Object o = c.newInstance() ;
  setRequestParams(o, request) ;
  return o ;
} // try catch block omitted for reasons of brevity
```

When calling this method, I have to cast the return result. Is there way I can write this method so I do not need to cast the returned object.

Comment: Why are you using `Class.forName(c.getName()).newInstance()` instead of `c.newInstance()`?

Comment: I have updated my question to use c.newInstance()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the method generic, and you can use the generic type parameter as the return type and the type parameter for the type of the parameter `c`, `Class` (which is currently raw).

```
public <T> T createUIBean(Class<T> c, HttpServletRequest request) {
  T o = c.newInstance();
  setRequestParams(o, request) ;
  return o ;
}
```

Also, `Class.forName(c.getName()).newInstance() ;` is too much to create a simple instance when `c.newInstance()` will do the job.

Comment: I will mark this as answer unless you object since you seem to +1 as well.

Comment: @user3586195 If you are asking me then I don't mind since this answer seems to be correct. Accepting answer is your call :)

Comment: I picked this one after a lot of inner conflict since it gives more information.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if that is what you want but maybe you are looking for something like [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

```
public <T> T createUIBean(Class<T> c, HttpServletRequest request) {
  T o = c.newInstance() ;// "Class.forName(c.getName())" is equivalent of "c"
  setRequestParams(o, request) ;
  return o ;
}
```

Now returned type `T` will be based on type `T` used as `Class<T> c` argument.